# SMOTE Filter of WEKA - How to interpret the result

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am currently struggling with a very imbalanced data set with 9 classes and a ratio of 12:1 between the most- and least-represented class. Applying weka's SMOTE filter until all classes were equally represented has drastically improved the classification results, from an overall classification accuracy of 86% to a classification accuracy of 95%. Individual class accuracys (true positive) have also been generally improved, before applying the SMOTE-filter they were ranging between 40%-99%, after applying the SMOTE filter between 94%-99%. Thereby, accuracies have been increasing with the number of times the SMOTE-filter was applied.

How reliable are those "new" results? Could this be more an effect of over-fitting?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give a heads up on my results in case somebody else stumbles on the same issue. Unfortunately, it seems like the accuracy improvements most likely came from over-fitting. 
I came to this conclusion by using a training-test-setup instead of cross-validation: I randomized my data, split it into two parts of 85% training data and 15% test data. Then I applied the SMOTE-filter on the training data until all classes were equally represented. This up-sampled data then trained a classification model (END-implementation) and the test-data was used for classification. Thereby, the classification results using this setup and SMOTE were very close to classification results without SMOTE, in total about 86%. It therefore seems the accuracy improvement came from the fact that the test-data in the cross-validation-setup is also up-scaled and therefore fostering over-fitting.

Does anybody know more about this? Or somebody who wants to challenge these findings?